# class 's property in iOS

Tags: ios, class, properties

I have a model like `car:NSObject`, it has property `name`, `color` and so on.
Now I have a `NSString *str=@"name";`, can I use it like this `[car str]`?
is it possible?

I tried:

```
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([_model class], &propertyCount);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < propertyCount; ++i) {
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    const char * Cname = property_getName(property);
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithCString:Cname encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}
```

but it does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to dive directly into the Objective-C runtime.

If your class is key-value compliant, you can use `-valueForKey:` like so:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// Declare the car.
@interface Car : NSObject

// Automatic properties are key-value compliant.
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * color;

@end

@implementation Car
@end

// Entrypoint for command-line app to prove that this works
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        // First, create our car.
        Car * car = [[Car alloc] init];
        car.name = @"My First Car";
        car.color = @"White";

        // Declare variables holding the names of the properties we want to access
        NSString * nameKey = @"name";
        NSString * colorKey = @"color";

        // Retrieve the values of those properties
        NSString * name = [car valueForKey:nameKey];
        NSString * color = [car valueForKey:colorKey];

        // Do something with the result.
        NSLog(@"My car '%@' is '%@'.", name, color);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `[car name]` can be done as (since it's a method that takes an object pointer and returns an object pointer) `[car performSelector:@selector(name)]`, and if you want to provide the selector dynamically from a string, you can do:

```
NSString *str = @"name";
NSString *name = [car performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(str)];
```